# How can I create a branch from an Argo workflow?

Tags: github-api, argo-workflows

I am trying to send a HTTP post request in Argo workflows to create a branch in GitHub. It keeps failing and I am not able to figure out why. It looks like something sticky and small, and I would appreciate any help in figuring this out.

While executing, I just see a message `successCondition 'response.statusCode == 201' evaluated false`. I don't see anything in logs.

Here is my workflow:

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: http-template-
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  serviceAccountName: argo-workflow-sa
  templates:
    - name: main
      steps:
        
        - - name: getmainsha
            template: get-sha
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: url
                  value: "https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/git/refs/heads/main"

        - - name: print-main-sha
            template: print
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: message
                  value: "{{=jsonpath(steps.getmainsha.outputs.result, '$.object.sha')}}"

        - - name: generate-branch-name
            template: generate-unique-name
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: string-name
                  value: "new-branch"

        - - name: create-branch-github
            template: create-branch-post
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: url
                  value: "https://api.github.com/repos/<owner>/<repo>/git/refs"
                - name: branch-name
                  value: "{{steps.generate-branch-name.outputs.result}}"
                - name: main-branch-sha
                  value: "{{=jsonpath(steps.getmainsha.outputs.result, '$.object.sha')}}"
        
    
  #--------------------------------------------------------------templates-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#  

    - name: print
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: message
      container:
        image: docker/whalesay:latest
        command: [cowsay]
        args: ["{{inputs.parameters.message}}"]

    - name: get-sha
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: url
      http:
        timeoutSeconds: 20 # Default 30
        url: "{{inputs.parameters.url}}"
        method: "GET"
        headers:
          - name: "Accept"
            value: "application/vnd.github+json"
          - name: "Authorization"
            value: "Bearer <Token>"
          - name: "X-GitHub-Api-Version"
            value: "2022-11-28"
        successCondition: "response.statusCode == 200"

    - name: generate-unique-name
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: string-name
      script:
        image: python:alpine3.6
        command: [python]
        source: |
          import random
          i = random.randint(1, 1000)
          print('refs/heads/'+'{{inputs.parameters.string-name}}'+'-'+str(i))

    - name: create-branch-post
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: url
          - name: branch-name
          - name: main-branch-sha
      http:
        timeoutSeconds: 20 # Default 30
        url: "{{inputs.parameters.url}}"
        method: "POST"
        headers:
          - name: "Accept"
            value: "application/vnd.github+json"
          - name: "Authorization"
            value: "Bearer <Token>"
          - name: "X-GitHub-Api-Version"
            value: "2022-11-28"
        body: "{'ref':{{inputs.parameters.branch-name}},'sha':{{inputs.parameters.main-branch-sha}}}"
        successCondition: "response.statusCode == 201"
```

I expect a branch to be created in GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So silly of me to make this mistake.

As per the official github documentation the ref in the request body should be like this `"ref":"refs/heads/<branch-name>"`.

Github api [create reference](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/refs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-reference)

Here is the updated template

```
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: expand-pvc-template-
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  serviceAccountName: argo-workflow-sa
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: uri
        value: "<github-uri>"
  templates:
    - name: main
      steps:
        - - name: create-branch-github
            template: github-http-post-put
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: url
                  value: "{{workflow.parameters.uri}}/git/refs"
                - name: method
                  value: "POST"
                - name: requestbody
                  value: |
                    {
                      "ref":"refs/heads/new-branch",
                      "sha":"<main-branch-sha>"
                    }
                - name: success-condition
                  value: "response.statusCode == 201"
--------------------------------------------------------

    - name: github-http-post
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: url
          - name: method
          - name: requestbody
          - name: success-condition
      http:
        timeoutSeconds: 30
        url: "{{inputs.parameters.url}}"
        method: "{{inputs.parameters.method}}"
        headers:
          - name: "Accept"
            value: "application/vnd.github+json"
          - name: "Authorization"
            value: "Bearer <>"
          - name: "X-GitHub-Api-Version"
            value: "2022-11-28"
        body: "{{inputs.parameters.requestbody}}"
        successCondition: "{{inputs.parameters.success-condition}}"
```